# Calculating the width of an element?

Tags: php, html, width

I'm trying to get the width of a div so that I can echo it out in php.

Can anyone give me a pointer as how to achieve this?

Basically, I'm wanting to develop a 'responsive' `<div>` which will display the width of the parent `<div>` in php in a responsive template. Obviously, in different window sizes, the responsive template changes width size and I just need to find a way to output this width and echo it out in php. JQuery is already running in the background, so I could tap into that...

Just need a bit of direction

Comment: You cannot get the width of a `div` in PHP because the HTML has not been rendered. You can only get the width of rendered elements with a *client-side* language - JavaScript.

Comment: PHP is server side scripting language. you can not get width of div by PHP. it can be done by jquery or javascript. can you provide code so that i can give u solution.

Comment: @user3313268 show use the code of the div that you would like to get the width of

Comment: Thanks guys. Basically, I'm wanting to develop a 'responsive' <div> which will display the width of the parent <div> in php in a responsive template. Obviously, in different window sizes, the responsive template changes width size and I just need to find a way to output this width and echo it out in php. JQuery is already running in the background, so I could tap into that... Just need a bit of direction

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is going to run server side. You'll only be able to determine width client side (e.g. using javascript) after the DOM is generated. You can do so with plain javascript by doing

```
document.getElementById("yourDivId").offsetWidth
```

or using jQuery

```
$("#yourDivId").width()
```

If you really need the width accessible in your PHP code, you will then need to send a post request (ajax or full) so that PHP can have the value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, because PHP runs on the server, users will visit the page from their browser, which is usually a different computer. After a user enters a web address into the address bar and hits enter, a GET request will be sent to the server of the page being requested. The server will run a server-side script (in PHP, for instance), generate the structure of the page and send that structure to the client-side, that is, the browser. When the server has sent the structure to the browser, the PHP code was already successfully finished, but the structure was not displayed yet, therefore your `div`s do not exist yet at that point, let alone having any `width` values.

So, the behavior you intended to achieve is impossible with PHP, therefore you should do it in a different way. May I recomment Javascript with jquery? For instance, if your outer `div` has `id="a"` and the inner `div` has `id="b"`, then you can do the following in Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#a").resize(function() {
        $("#b").text($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Here, you have a `function` which will run at load event and then will register a `resize` event to the outer `div`, which will change the inner text of the inner `div` according to the `width` of the outer `div`.